# Only one Annotation showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sdk

Hi my array is filled with three objects and only 1 annotation is showing on the map. Any ideas? If i NSLog certain elements it is filled. Just cant get the 3 annotations to show.

```
NSMutableArray *currentBranch = [xmlParser branch];
int counter=[currentBranch count];

NSMutableArray *new = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
Mapdets * myAnn;
myAnn = [[Mapdets alloc] init];

[mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0 }};
region.center.latitude = -33.86434888;
region.center.longitude = 151.2090236;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 55.80f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 55.80f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)

{
 Mapdets *currentBranch = [[xmlParser branch] objectAtIndex:i];




NSString *title = currentBranch.title;
NSString *subtitle = currentBranch.subtitle;
NSString *lat = currentBranch.lat;  
NSString *lng = currentBranch.lng;     


coordinates.latitude = [lat doubleValue];  
coordinates.longitude = [lng doubleValue];

    myAnn.coordinate = coordinates;
    myAnn.title = title;
    myAnn.subtitle = subtitle;

 NSLog(@"%@",  title);

 [new addObject:myAnn];
}

[mapview addAnnotations:new];
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [mapview addAnnotations:new]; keep this in for loop

Comment: What is your map zoom Level...See your coordinates are in region or not...Check your for loop..Its bracket are over before the annotation added

Comment: @Murali I moved it into the for loop, and same problem.

Comment: @Nit, i have it set to see the whole map, and no its not there. ( i thought of this in the beginning)

Comment: did u check the count of new after for loop?..if it is 1 then try with initialize myAnn in for loop..

Comment: @Murali You are a legend!!! Worked Perfect. Can you post it as a answer and ill mark it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialise myAnn in for loop..

```
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
    Mapdets * myAnn;
    myAnn = [[Mapdets alloc] init];
    Mapdets *currentBranch = [[xmlParser branch] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *title = currentBranch.title;
    NSString *subtitle = currentBranch.subtitle;
    NSString *lat = currentBranch.lat;  
    NSString *lng = currentBranch.lng;     

    coordinates.latitude = [lat doubleValue];  
    coordinates.longitude = [lng doubleValue];

    myAnn.coordinate = coordinates;
    myAnn.title = title;
    myAnn.subtitle = subtitle;

    NSLog(@"%@",  title);
   [new addObject:myAnn];
}
```